# How to disable ggtags' *ggtags-global* buffer scrolling?

Tags: scrolling, compile-mode, ggtags

when I do `next-error`, the `*ggtags-global*` buffer scrolls down one line.

I hope that the `*ggtags-global*` buffer doesn't scroll, whether it's executing `next-error`, `previous-error`, or `compile-goto-error`.

By default it scrolls which is annoying:
[image]

Comment: It'll eventually have to scroll (e.g. when the next error is off the screen). You might want to specify what you want to do in that case.

Comment: @NickD 
when the next error is off the screen, it can scroll down one line, when the previous error is off the screen, it can scroll up one line.

Comment: @NickD Other than that, don't scroll under any circumstances, When the current error is at the border of the screen, I can use the mouse wheel to scroll down or up multiple lines at once.

Comment: In similar circumstances, `grep` uses a `*grep*` buffer which scrolls by half the height of the window, thereby putting the current error in the middle of the window. I don't know why `ggtags` doesn't do that, but it seems to me that that's a better way to deal with the next "error" being outside the window : if you scroll by one line, then on the next `next-error` you'd have to scroll again. BTW, if you switch to the `*ggtags*` buffer and say `C-h v next-error-function`, what is the result? Also, what is the result of  `C-h v next-error-hook`? Please update the question with this information.

Comment: @NickD In the `*ggtags-global*` buffer: `next-error-function` value is `compilation-next-error-function`, `next-error-hook` value is `ggtags-global-next-error-function`

Comment: ... which is what `grep` uses for `next-error-function`. I don't understand why `ggtags` behaves differently. [Later] I did not have `ggtags` or `global` installed, so I couldn't really test, but I was intrigued enough to do the installation and try it: I don't get the scrolling that you get. I get the same scrolling that I get with `grep`: half a screenful if necessary, then no scrolling until it is necessary, then half a screenful again. Can you try with `grep` and see what kind of behavior you get?

Comment: @NickD grep is the same as ggtags scrolling, my emacs version is 27.2, installed via dnf on a fedora 35.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133129/discussion-between-nickd-and-dongli-si).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scrolling happens in `compilation-set-window`.

Its definition in my Emacs is

```lisp
(defsubst compilation-set-window (w mk)
  "Maybe align the compilation output window W with marker MK near top."
  (cond ((integerp compilation-context-lines)
         (set-window-start w (save-excursion
                               (goto-char mk)
                               (compilation-beginning-of-line
                                (- 1 compilation-context-lines))
                               (point))))
        ((and (null compilation-context-lines)
              ;; If there is no left fringe.
              (equal (car (window-fringes w)) 0))
         (set-window-start w (save-excursion
                               (goto-char mk)
                               (beginning-of-line 1)
                               (point)))))
  (set-window-point w mk))
```

Changing it to

```lisp
(defsubst compilation-set-window (w mk)
  "Maybe align the compilation output window W with marker MK near top."
  (unless (pos-visible-in-window-p mk w)
    (cond ((integerp compilation-context-lines)
           (set-window-start w (save-excursion
                                 (goto-char mk)
                                 (compilation-beginning-of-line
                                  (- 1 compilation-context-lines))
                                 (point))))
          ((and (null compilation-context-lines)
                ;; If there is no left fringe.
                (equal (car (window-fringes w)) 0))
           (set-window-start w (save-excursion
                                 (goto-char mk)
                                 (beginning-of-line 1)
                                 (point))))))
  (set-window-point w mk))
```

accomplishes the desired behavior of not scrolling unless the position is not visible.  You may need to tweak it a bit, especially if using `compilation-context-lines` or if some custom scrolling is desired (as opposed to aligning near top).

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe that this scrolls the output buffer (i.e. where the "error" occurs), *not* the compilation buffer. In support of this, I get a "scroll by half-window" effect, not a "scroll-by-one-line" effect, even though I don't have this change in my emacs (and I've tried both a recent upstream and 27.2).

Comment: That's not true, the output buffer is the buffer with the list of errors (or references in the case of ggtags — the `*ggtags-global*` buffer).  Note that you need to eval the new definition of `compilation-set-window` and then re-eval `compilation-goto-locus` for it to work.

Comment: @d125q This solved my problem, and I found that my scrolling behavior was caused by the fact that I had (fringe-mode 0) set. thank.